# making divs as array items and adding to list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the html structure like this, where I am trying to insert each .blueText into each .blue...The divs with class blue is dynamically generated and the task is to add the blueText through JQuery.

```
<div class="blueText">test 1</div>
<div class="blueText">test 2</div>
<div class="blueText">test 3</div>
<div class="blueText">test 4</div>
<div class="blueText">test 5</div>


<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

This method works

```
var blueText = [ 'test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3', 'test 4', 'test 5'];
    $('.blue').each(function (k) {
    $(this).append(blueText[k]);
    });
```

But how do I make this work instead of hard coding the text as an array

Answer (score 2):

To move the `.blueText` elements inside the `.blue` elements, you'd do:

```
var text = $('.blueText');

$('.blue').append(function(i,el) {
    return text.eq(i);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZUqf/10/)

To just append the text from the `.blueText` elements to `.blue` :

```
var text = $('.blueText');

$('.blue').text(function(i) {
    return text.eq( i ).text();
});
```